# npx expo start --tunnel : [ERR_UNKNOWN_ENCODING]: Unknown encoding: base64url

Tags: npm, expo

When trying to launch expo strart through an ngrok tunnel, I get the following error :

```
$ npx expo start --tunnel
Starting project at C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx
Starting Metro Bundler
CommandError: TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_ENCODING]: Unknown encoding: base64url
```

I am on Windows and I'm using `expo sdk 46` at it's latest version and `@expo/ngrok@^4.1.0`. This error does not occur when trying to load `npx expo start` locally. Any idea why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your **settings.json** to this:

```
{
  "urlRandomness": "h8-ur9",
  "dev": true,
  "minify": false,
  "https": false,
  "hostType": "tunnel",
  "lanType": "ip",
  "scheme": null,
  "devClient": false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`base64url` encoding was added in Node.js 16.0.0. Try upgrading Node if you are on an older version.

Comment: I've upgraded to v16.17.0 and it still doesn't seem to work. `node -v` : v16.17.0 and `npm -v` : 8.18.0

Comment: I suspect the error is coming from `node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/AsyncNgrok.js` though you can grep for "base64url" to find possible call sites or run with `EXPO_DEBUG=1` to make the CLI print out a full stack trace. Add a console log statement that prints your Node version to verify you are actually running Node 16.

Comment: thanks for the insight. I'll look into that direction. It does seem to be ngrok specific